# Web Service without the .asmx extension

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx

I am Mocking a web service from it's wsdl file.
In the original wsdl I see:

```
  <soap:address location="http://localhost:13080/Core/ws/broker"/>
```

In my implementation I have:

```
<soap12:address location="http://localhost:13080/Core/ws/broker/Broker.asmx"/>
```

How I can remove asmx part from the path `Broker.asmx` that my service can be called as the original service.

Answer (score 1):

If it's hosted in IIS, you could set "broker.asmx" as default document. So, when you open ..../ws/broker, IIS will automatically assume that you meant .../ws/broker/broker.asmx